# SparkR dubt and Broken pipe exception

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

Hi I'm working on SparkR in distribuited mode with yarn cluster.

I have two question :

**1) If I made a script that contains R line code and SparkR line code, it will distribute just the SparkR code or simple R too?**

This is the script. I read a csv and take just the 100k first record.
I clean it (with R function) deleting NA values and created a SparkR dataframe. 
This is what it do: foreach Lineset take each TimeInterval where that LineSet appear and sum some attribute (numeric attribute), after that put them all into a Matrix.

This is the script with R and SparkR code. It takes 7h in standalone mode and like 60h in distributed mode (killed by  `java.net.SocketException`: Broken Pipe)

```
LineSmsInt<-fread("/home/sentiment/Scrivania/LineSmsInt.csv")
Short<-LineSmsInt[1:100000,]
Short[is.na(Short)] <- 0
Short$TimeInterval<-Short$TimeInterval/1000
ShortDF<-createDataFrame(sqlContext,Short)
UniqueLineSet<-unique(Short$LINESET)
UniqueTime<-unique(Short$TimeInterval)
UniqueTime<-as.numeric(UniqueTime)
Row<-length(UniqueLineSet)*length(UniqueTime)
IntTemp<-matrix(nrow =Row,ncol=7)
k<-1

colnames(IntTemp)<-c("LINESET","TimeInterval","SmsIN","SmsOut","CallIn","CallOut","Internet")
Sys.time()
for(i in 1:length(UniqueLineSet)){
  SubSetID<-filter(ShortDF,ShortDF$LINESET==UniqueLineSet[i])
  for(j in 1:length(UniqueTime)){
    SubTime<-filter(SubSetID,SubSetID$TimeInterval==UniqueTime[j])       
    IntTemp[k,1]<-UniqueLineSet[i]
    IntTemp[k,2]<-as.numeric(UniqueTime[j])
    k3<-collect(select(SubTime,sum(SubTime$SmsIn)))
    IntTemp[k,3]<-k3[1,1]
    k4<-collect(select(SubTime,sum(SubTime$SmsOut)))
    IntTemp[k,4]<-k4[1,1]
    k5<-collect(select(SubTime,sum(SubTime$CallIn)))
    IntTemp[k,5]<-k5[1,1]
    k6<-collect(select(SubTime,sum(SubTime$CallOut)))
    IntTemp[k,6]<-k6[1,1]
    k7<-collect(select(SubTime,sum(SubTime$Internet)))
    IntTemp[k,7]<-k7[1,1]
    k<-k+1
  }
  print(UniqueLineSet[i])
  print(i)
}
```

This is the script R the only things that change is the subset function and of course is a normal R data.frame not SparkR dataframe.
It takes 1.30 minute in standalone mode.
Why it's so fast just in R and it's so slowly in SparkR?

```
for(i in 1:length(UniqueLineSet)){
  SubSetID<-subset.data.frame(LineSmsInt,LINESET==UniqueLineSet[i])
  for(j in 1:length(UniqueTime)){
    SubTime<-subset.data.frame(SubSetID,TimeInterval==UniqueTime[j])
    IntTemp[k,1]<-UniqueLineSet[i]
    IntTemp[k,2]<-as.numeric(UniqueTime[j])
    IntTemp[k,3]<-sum(SubTime$SmsIn,na.rm = TRUE)
    IntTemp[k,4]<-sum(SubTime$SmsOut,na.rm = TRUE)
    IntTemp[k,5]<-sum(SubTime$CallIn,na.rm = TRUE)
    IntTemp[k,6]<-sum(SubTime$CallOut,na.rm = TRUE)
    IntTemp[k,7]<-sum(SubTime$Internet,na.rm=TRUE)
    k<-k+1
  }
  print(UniqueLineSet[i])
  print(i)
}
```

**2) First script, in distribuited mode, was killed by  :**

> java.net.SocketException: Broken Pipe

and this appear too sometimes:

> java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out

**It may comes from a bad configuration? suggestion?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't take this the wrong way but it is not a particularly well written piece of code. It is already inefficient using core R and adding SparkR to the equation makes it even worse.

> If I made a script that contains R line code and SparkR line code, it will distribute just the SparkR code or simple R too?

Unless you're using distributed data structures and functions which operate on these structures it is just a plain R code executed in a single thread on the master.

> Why it's so fast just in R and it's so slowly in SparkR?

For starters you execute a single job for each combination of `LINESET`, `UniqueTime` and column. Each time Spark has scan all records and fetch data to the driver.

Moreover using Spark to handle data that can be easily handled in memory of a single machine simply doesn't make sense. Cost of running the job in case like this is usually much higher than a cost of actual processing.

> suggestion?

If you really want to use SparkR just `groupBy` and `agg`:

```
group_by(Short, Short$LINESET, Short$TimeInterval) %>% agg(
  sum(Short$SmsIn), sum(Short$SmsOut), sum(Short$CallIn),
  sum(Short$CallOut), sum(Short$Internet))
```

If you care about missing (`LINESET`, `TimeInterval`) pairs fill these using either `join` or `unionAll`.

In practice it would simply stick with a `data.table` and aggregate locally:

```
Short[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by=.(LINESET, TimeInterval)]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried with this difference function (that I didn't know) and it works of course. It's pretty fast now. 
I'm a newmbie in sparkR (spark too). Do you have some link about sparkR (over sparkR officially documentation)?

Comment: Not really, but I don't use SparkR so I've never looked for something like this. Still, you can use any general Spark / SparkSQL reference. There is no difference here.

Comment: I have another dubt , createDataFrame is distribuite on the cluster?

And there is any difference if I read file from hdfs or from a simple csv?(For the distribution I mean)

Comment: Yes there is a difference. In general you should probably avoid parallelizing local data structures for anything else than prototyping   and testing.